# base-href in head of HTML seems to be ignored for all assets loaded

Tags: html, browser

Maybe I just have this whole idea wrong, so lets check this out. I have the following HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <base href="/xyz"> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <app-root></app-root>
    <script src="runtime.js" defer=""></script><script src="polyfills.js" defer=""></script><script src="main.js" defer=""></script></body>
</html>
```

Now, when I try to load this in the browser with the following url: http://localhost:8080/xyz
it loads the index.html but for all the assets (styles and javascript files) I get 404

[image]

I would expect, because I have that **base href="/xyz"** that it would prefix all asset urls with that url, but as you can see it doesn't.

For completeness, here is my file structure:

```
./server.js
./xyz/index.html
      styles.css
      .....
```

So the server is serving all the files from the **/xyz** path

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Relative paths are resolved by taking the base URL (`http://localhost:8080/xyz`), removing everything after the last `/` in the path (giving you `http://localhost:8080/`) and then appending the new path (`http://localhost:8080/styles.css`).

If you want `/xyz/styles.css` then you need to put a `/` on the end of your base path: `<base href="/xyz/">`

Comment: ok, that makes sense. The solution, in. my case, is to set the base href to: **.**